# How to add more inputs depend dropdown values (PHP, JS)

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgresql

so I want to add some input based on the option value from the drop down that will be selected. For example, the dropdown looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="job" id="job" >
        <option value="">position</option>
        <option value="1">Teacher</option>
        <option value="2">Principal</option>
        <option value="3">Staff</option>      
    </select>
</form>
```

and if the selected value is number 1 or teacher, it will display new input like this below it:

```
<input type="number" name="student" id="student">
<input type="Text" name="class" id="class">
```

if you guys know how to make it, maybe you can help me with this please, either using php or js because I've been stuck with this problem for a long time.

Comment: Lookup `onChange` event on Google.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to achieve what you want depends on what framwwork you are using.

For

- vanilla JS: [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to control css OR append html.
- jQuery: $("#class").hide() / .show();
- Angular: ngIf
- vueJs: v-if / v-show

etc...

Answer (score 0):

before that, set the style of input is hide, then You can try onchange on select, Which is get the value of select. then proceed to show the hide input.

```js
const job = document.getElementById("job");
let add = document.getElementsByClassName("addEx");

job.addEventListener("change",function() {
    if (this.value == 1) {
       for (let i = 0; i < add.length; i++) {
           add[i].style.display = 'block';
       } 
    } 
    else {
        for (let i = 0; i < add.length; i++) {
            add[i].style.display = 'none';
        } 
    }
});
```

```css
.addEx {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="job" id="job" >
        <option value="">position</option>
        <option value="1">Teacher</option>
        <option value="2">Principal</option>
        <option value="3">Staff</option>      
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="student" id="student" class="addEx">
    <input type="Text" name="class" id="class" class="addEx">
</form>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#job').change(function() {
    let job = $('#job').val();
    if (job == '1') {
      $('#sampleBox').show();
    } else {
      $('#sampleBox').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#sampleBox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="job" id="job">
  <option selected hidden disabled>Position</option>
  <option value="1">Teacher</option>
  <option value="2">Principal</option>
  <option value="3">Staff</option>
</select>

<div id="sampleBox">
  <input type="number" name="student" id="student">
  <input type="Text" name="class" id="class">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can do that by adding `change` event listener to the `<select></select>` element;

and each time the selected `<option></option>` changes you should make all `inputs` hidden then make the ones you want visible.

> Example:
>
> ```js
> const select = document.getElementById('job');
> select.addEventListener('change', function() {
>   // returns the selected option's value 
>   const selectedOption = select.value;
>   // makes all inputs hidden each time the selected option changes.
>   document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => input.style.display = "none");
>   // for 1st parameter, pass the option value.
>   // for 2nd parameter, pass an array of ids of the inputs you want to make them visible.
>   const setInputs = (state, id) => {
>     if (selectedOption === state) {
>       (id.sup ? id = [id] : id);
>       id.forEach(i => {
>         try {
>           document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
>         } catch (error) {
>           console.error(`#${i} doesn't exists!`)
>         }
>       });
>     }
>   }
>
>   /* if the selected option's value is 1(Teacher),
>      The "student" and "class" inputs will be visible. */
>   setInputs('1', ['student', 'class']);
>   /* if the selected option's value is 2(Principal),
>      The "id" and "principal" inputs will be visible. */
>   setInputs('2', ['id', 'principal']);
>   /* if the selected option's value is 3(Staff),
>      The "name" input will be visible. */
>   /* if you want to show just one input, 
>      don't need to pass an array as 2nd parameter
>      just pass a string */
>   setInputs('3', 'name');
> });
> ```
>
> ```css
> /* Makes all inputs hidden by default */
>
> input {
>   display: none;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <form action="#" method="post">
>   <select name="job" id="job">
>     <option selected hidden disabled>Position</option>
>     <option value="1">Teacher</option>
>     <option value="2">Principal</option>
>     <option value="3">Staff</option>
>   </select>
>
>   <input type="number" name="student" id="student" placeholder="Student">
>   <input type="Text" name="class" id="class" placeholder="class">
>
>   <input type="number" name="id" id="id" placeholder="ID">
>   <input type="number" name="principal" id="principal" placeholder="Principal">
>
>   <input type="Text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
> </form>
> ```